# Getting Conda HTTP Error in Windows while trying to update any package

Tags: python, anaconda

I am failing to understand why there is conda http error.

```
CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url <https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64/current_repodata.json>
Elapsed: -

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.

If your current network has https://www.anaconda.com blocked, please file
a support request with your network engineering team.

'https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64'
```

I can clearly go to https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64 using browser and am able to download any package or file from there.

I don't know the proxy server of my organization or else I would have tried updating .condarc as mentioned in https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/proxy/.

Is there a way to address this issue in windows so that I don't have to call IT each time I update a package or create a conda env?

Thanks in advance for any kind help.

Comment: Alternatively is there a way that I can download the contents of https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64 in my local machine and install it from there?

Answer (score 1):

The Error may be due to your Firewall (and not due to Proxy Server).
If that is the case, a permanent solution can be allowing the .exe program thru firewall.

1. Access Windows Firewall with Advanced Security (You may need admin privilege). For Example, enter at command prompt wf.
2. Add to the Inbound Rules. Click on the link in opened window: Inbound Rules
3. Select Rule Type: Program.
4. Next let the executable program thru the firewall. e.g., C:\conda\envs\my_virtual_environment\Lib\site-packages\pythonwin\Pythonwin.exe

---

As a side not the internet talks about disabling ssl in .condarc -but that is not recommended (at least it did not help me). Mosr likely than not, you don't need to tweak .condarc.